# Password security: Ubuntu Forums Security Breach

Tags: security

If the passwords were encrypted is there really a problem?

I have not used the forum for some time and can't remember the details.

Advice please.

Comment: You can get detailed answer, if you ask this question at [security.se]

Answer (score 2):

Even if the passwords are encrypted the PCs these days have become powerful enough to use [bruteforce attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) on the hash to find the passwords within reasonable time. I myself don't remember the forum password I used to use. So to be on the safer side, it would be prudent to change the password in websites where you feel that you've used the same password.

**Update:**
Canonical in its statement on the Ubuntu forums home page, has told:

> The passwords are not stored in plain text, they are stored as salted
>   hashes. However, if you were using the same password as your Ubuntu
>   Forums one on another service (such as email), you are strongly
>   encouraged to change the password on the other service ASAP.

The use of salt will make it more difficult to find the password from the hash, but still it'll be safer to change the password, wherever required. To know more about Salt, please check out: [Salt (cryptography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)